# How to call a method in lambda expression to run in Entity Framework?

Tags: entity-framework, lambda, expression

I have a query and give it to `Entity Framework` to run:

```
using (var context = new MyEFContext())
{
    var result = context.Items.Select(item => new {Type = item.GetType()}).ToList();
}
```

But I encountered an exception for calling System methods like `GetType()` :(

```
LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.Type GetType()' method,
and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.
```

I tried dynamic creation of lambda expression but running dynamic expressions has same problem.
How to give a method in form of lambda expression to `Entity Frameworkenter`?

Comment: The error says that `GetType` can't be converted to an SQL statement, so you can't do this at all. You can just convert to an `IEnumerable<Item>` and call `Enumerable.Select` instead.

Comment: Thanks @Lee. I want to get a list of entities from entity framework. But not all fields of entities, assume I want only "Id"s of entities. So I have to create a query that gives required fields as a new dynamic type (anonymous type). Now I need knowing type of primary entity, so I tried getting type of entity using GetType method into expression body. And unfortunately it doesn't work. How to do this?

Comment: Maybe the question should be: why do you need the type? Apparently you have an inheritance tree that you want to query by the base type. A assume that after the query you branch off into different behaviors based upon the type. Maybe you can turn it around: branch first and get the subtypes you need for each branch separately.

Answer (score 2):

You just need to call the ToList() before Select()

```
using (var context = new MyEFContext())
{
    var result = context.Items.ToList().Select(item => new {Type = item.GetType()}).ToList();
}
```

This will execute the context.Items.ToList() part first which is by the Entity framework and then the Select works as in a local List outside the EF

if you want only one field

```
var result = (from item in  context.Items
select new 
{ 
field = item.yourfield
}).ToList().Select(p=> new {Type = p.field.GetType()}).ToList();
```

Comment: Thanks @Tinu. But your way is very heavy and has very bad performance. Assume I wand one and only one field of my heavy related tables, your way brings all fields of all related tables into client and then selects that required field.

Comment: Edited the Answer, you can specify to get the column name that you want to get which will get only one field and then do the get type

Comment: This way is heavy too. If you call `.ToList()` method befor `.Select()` this means that all entities will be pushed to client application and it is not good idea.

Comment: if you want only one then change it to FirstorDefault() or put a where clause to limit the records

Comment: "One" column was an example. It is possible selection of 1,2,3,... or even all columns.

Comment: Where clause filters some rows, but all columns will be selected.

Answer (score 1):

You need to call `AsEnumerable()` so that you'll evaluate `GetType` with Linq-To-Objects, not Linq-To-Entities. There is no concept of `GetType` in SQL, it needs to be evaluated in the CLR:

```
 using (var context = new MyEFContext())
 {
      var result = context.Items.AsEnumerable().Select(item => new {Type = item.GetType()}).ToList();
 }
```

Not sure how useful this is, as you'll end up getting a list of your `Item` type...

Comment: Thanks @Chris Hardie. But if Link To SQL executes and result produces then type of every item will be anonymous because of selection of some fields as new dynamic type: `item => new {Type = item.GetType()}`

Answer (score 1):

Use below code :

```
using (var context = new MyEFContext())
 {
      var result = context.Items.AsEnumerable().ToList().Select(item => new {Type = item.GetType()}).ToList();
 }
```

`item.GetType()` function is a code function and must be run in client. In your code `GetType` function wanted to run on the server. When you use `ToList()` all item pushed in the client and you can run `GetType()` function on it.

**EDIT1**

You Can Create `GetType` Extended Stored procedure and use below code :

```
using (var context = new MyEFContext())
 {
      var result = context.Items.AsEnumerable().Select(item => new {Type = GetType(Item)}).ToList();
 }
```

In order to call function in Linq use following link : [Calling Functions in LINQ](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd456828%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: Thanks @Mehdi Lotfi. Supplicate you to read my comment at above post (Chris Harie's post).